Spacing between tcbtheorem number and title (and different fonts for these)
I want a space between the number in a tcbtheorem and the theorem title, as in the image (from Sheldon Axler's 'Measure, Integration & Real Analysis').

I would also like to have different fonts for the number and the theorem title (note that 'Definition' is in bold, while the number '1.1' is not). I can already get the title and description in different fonts and adjust the spacing too, see below for a MWE.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\tcbset{
    defnstyle/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries, separator sign= {\,\,\,\,}, description font=\itshape\bfseries, theorem number and name}
}


\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{defn}%
{Definition}{defnstyle}{defn}

\begin{document}
    \section{a section}
    \begin{defn}{a description}{}
        This is a definition.
    \end{defn}
\end{document}

Output:


Welcome to TeX.SX!

You can use the number freestyle key as follows (see section 5 of the manual for more details)
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\tcbset{
    defnstyle/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries, separator sign= {\,\,\,\,}, description font=\itshape\bfseries, theorem number and name}
}


\newtcbtheorem[number within=section,%
number freestyle=%
{\noexpand\textnormal{\noexpand\thesection.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}\noexpand\hspace{0.5em}}}]%
{defn}%
{Definition}{defnstyle}{defn}

\begin{document}
    \section{a section}
    \begin{defn}{a description}{}
        This is a definition.
    \end{defn}
\end{document}

Output:


This solution is not really compatible with cleveref since it adds the extra space when using the \cref command. Maybe someone else can provide an alternative solution?

@Hernán as an ugly fix, you could include \newcommand{\rf}[1]{\cref{#1}\hspace{-0.5em}} in your preamble and work with \rf instead.

With keytheorems, all the parameters you mention are under your control, and you can easily wrap theorems from amsthm in a tcolorbox. It also works as expected with hyperref and cleveref. This should get you started.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{keytheorems}
\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\tcbset{
  defibox/.style={
    colback=yellow!20,
    colbacktitle=yellow!40,
    coltitle=black,
    arc=4mm,
    toptitle=2mm,
    bottomtitle=2mm,
    boxsep=0.5mm,
    left=2mm,
    right=2mm
    }
}

\newkeytheoremstyle{tcb-defibox}
  {
    tcolorbox=defibox,
    notebraces={}{},
    notefont=\itshape\rmfamily,
    headfont=\bfseries\sffamily,
    numberfont=\mdseries,
    headpunct={},
    noteseparator={}, % default is one space, remove since controlling space below
    headformat=\NUMBER\quad\NAME\quad\NOTE,
  }
\newkeytheorem{definition}[parent=section,style=tcb-defibox]

\begin{document}

\section{Some section}

\begin{definition}[note=partition,label=foo]
Suppose $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$. A \emph{partition} of $[a,b]$ is a finite list of the form $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n$, where
    \[ a=x_0<x_1<\dots<x_n=b. \]
\end{definition}

Refer to \cref{foo}

\end{document}


